# Is there an option in segmented function in R to specify a segmented variable in case of adjusted segmented/breakpoint analysis?

Tags: r

I want to run an adjusted segmented/breakpoint/changepoint analysis. The main predictor of interest is age. I am interested in estimating a breakpoint for age while adjusting for race, sex and education. Below is my code:

```
o <- lm(ab42~race+sex+educ, data=merged)
o.seg <- segmented(o, seg.Z = age+race+sex+educ, psi=list(age=NA,race=NA,sex=NA,educ=NA))
```

When I run the above code, it gives me breakpoints for all the variables listed in the psi option. I want to do segmentation only on age.

How can I specify this in the segmented function?

```
o <- lm(ab42~race+sex+educ, data=merged)
o.seg <- segmented(o, seg.Z = age+race+sex+educ, psi=list(age=NA,race=NA,sex=NA,educ=NA))
```

Comment: in order to increase the probability of getting a response, please provide an example that it can be reproduced by just copy and paste into R console. It seems you are using some specific dataset, but I don't see the code for getting access to it. Try to use public datasets for your examples. Please take a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MrFlick - Please see the example using a public dataset. Here I want to do segmentation on VanKilled only.                                               library(segmented)
library(MASS)
data()
attach(Seatbelts)

#Linear Regression 
my.lm<-lm(DriversKilled ~ front + rear + kms, data=Seatbelts)
summary(my.lm)
#Segmented Regression
o<-segmented.lm(my.lm,seg.Z =~ VanKilled + front + rear + kms, psi=list(kms =NA, front=NA, rear=NA, VanKilled=NA), 
                control=seg.control(stop.if.error=FALSE,n.boot=0, it.max=20))
summary(o)
slope(o)
confint(o)